# Is making a small joke about a bishop mocking?

Tags: sin, terminology, morality, jokes

My friend was mentioning a bishop, so I bluntly made a joke "What? Like the chess piece?" I got a few laughs from my other Christian friends before that friend who mentioned a bishop said it was mocking Christianity. And it was running through my mind getting confused if I'd done something wrong or blasphemous, though I don't have a clear mind on what is blasphemous and what is not.

Side note: I am a Christian myself, and I'm trying to learn more about God and Grow more disciplined too, so I'm not very knowledgeable if it's a way of mocking.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We are different to other sites that ask questions on Christianity, primarily because we look for well researched questions and answers that provide evidence for claims made.  Please take our Tour to learn about us: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're asking about Catholic Bishops - although this might be equally true of people are styled as bishops in the different sects.

> I remember that Mr. Max Beerbohm (who has every merit except democracy) attempted to analyse the jokes at which the mob laughs. He divided them into three sections: jokes about bodily humiliation, jokes about things alien, such as foreigners, and jokes about bad cheese.
>
> [GKC - Popular Jokes and Vulgarity](https://library.chesterton.org/popular-jokes-and-vulgarity-57407)

I think we can classify these as jokes about "things alien"

Chesterton goes on to say that:

> Quite equally subtle and spiritual is the idea at the back of laughing at foreigners. It concerns the dark and delicate conception of a thing being like oneself and yet not like oneself. Nobody laughs at what is entirely foreign; nobody laughs at a palm-tree. But it is funny to see the familiar image of God disguised behind the black beard of a Frenchman or the black face of a Negro. There is nothing funny in the sounds that are wholly inhuman, the howling of wild beasts or of the wind. But if a man begins to talk like oneself, but all the syllables seem different, then if one is a man one feels inclined to laugh, though if one is a gentleman one resists the inclination.

So, to you and your friends, a Bishop evokes a foreign concept which you only understand as a chess piece, whereas to the Catholic a Bishop is your shepherd and all bishops are credited with the same respect by virtue of their office; by virtue of the trust that the Pope and the Holy Spirit has put in them.

But, as Chesterton pointed out quite bluntly, if you persist in the the idea of of "laughing at the black face of a negro", once it becomes familiar to you, then you would be a bigot.

The modern world wants to hold people accountable for things that the Catholic Church doesn't even want them condemning themselves for (such as things they're wholy ignorant of).

So no, making a joke (at least a non-phallic joke) about a chess piece is not mocking the faith, but like St. Paul said when he didn't want to eat pork for fear of scandalizing the Jews he was with, you should seek to avoid scandalizing your neighbor.  Especially one who feels ostracized for not laughing at something they may fear would end in blasphemy, even if the comment itself was not inherently mocking or blasphemous.

A lot, if not all, committed Catholics in the western world have a bit of a persecution complex, which sees persecution around every corner and in every comment.

So, I won't give you advice as to how to proceed since this is not the point of the site, but I do want to summarize by saying that it's probably not a big deal, but not worth repeating.

Comment: Not sure I agree with all your reasoning (in particular, the Beerbohm quote doesn't sound like it was meant seriously!  Though the St Paul reference, e.g. [Romans 14:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+14%3A21&version=NLT) or [1 Corinthians 10:32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+10%3A32&version=NLT) fits well).  In any case, your conclusions seem very sound: that there's nothing inherently wrong with making this sort of joke, but that it pays to be sensitive to your audience and avoid causing offence. (contd…)

Comment: …For me, the joke would be inherently wrong if it insulted or maligned bishops generally or one in particular, or if it made unfair or disparaging claims about them.  This does neither; I can imagine situations where it would be taken in good spirits and amusement without any risk of people being offended.  Similarly, I can't see how anyone could reasonably think OP was claiming that bishops _were_ literal chess pieces, and so I can't see any way it could be blasphemous.

Comment: I can't recall hearing this exact joke before, but I've heard humorous references to bishops only being able to move diagonally — which can be pretty funny.  I think if the opportunity ever arose to mention that to an actual bishop (in a friendly way, of course), the only reason I'd refrain would be in fear that they'd heard the joke before far too many times :-)

Comment: @gidds yeah, I was just validating the type of joke, because, when written, the joke doesn't seem much like a joke, but in reality (where the analysis of jokes is something one ought to avoid if one wants to retain ones sense of humor)  it is a type of joke.   If it weren't a joke in the first place, it might actually just be mocking so I wanted to get that out of the way

Comment: @gidds [especially when the church floor looks like this](https://cdn.britannica.com/04/121204-050-61ECC30E/choir-Westminster-Abbey-London.jpg)